# Get audio from a Flask server and showing audio in a playable format on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flask, audio, html5-audio

**Backstory**

I'm working on a music project that receives an audio file and separates piano stem from that audio. after separating the audio it will save the file locally on the api folder. then i'm sending a GET request from my React app to my flask api that return the audio file.

---

**What i need**

the problem is flask returns audio in a binary format(i'm not sure see the image below) and i want to know how to **show it in a playable format in React or at least save locally** in a audio format. thank you for any help.
[image: current output]

axios config

```
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:5000"
});
```

code on react side

```
try {
     const res = await api.get("/download");
     console.log(res);
   } catch (error) {
     console.log(error);
   }
```

code on the Flask api

```
@app.route('/download')
  @cross_origin()
   def download():
       
       instrument = 'piano'
   
       stem_path = f"backend/audio/{instrument}.wav"
       if os.path.isfile(stem_path):
           return send_file(stem_path, mimetype="audio/wav", as_attachment=True)
       else:
          return {"message": "cannot download stem"}, 401
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, that's a binary RIFF/WAV header.  Your client could could parse the binary response into an `ArrayBuffer` and create a `Blob` to play or save:

```js
setAudio(
  document.querySelector('audio'),
  'https://opus-bitrates.anthum.com/audio/music-96.opus',
)

async function setAudio(audio, url) {
  audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(
    new Blob([ await (await fetch(url)).arrayBuffer() ])
  )
}
```

```html
<audio controls></audio>
```

Comment: url = window.URL.createObjectURL(mp3);
 audio = new Audio(url);
 audio.load(); i have done up to this... can you tell how to play this audio on a <audio> element so that i can show it in the ui as  a audio player and users can play and pause the audio.

Comment: no! it just play when i click a button but not as a <audio> tag, is there any way i can put this as <audio src{} > something like this?

Comment: Run the code snippet above.  It loads and plays audio.

Comment: it worked thank you sooo much, u helped me a lot!